# Write the output of str() to a text file?

Tags: r

`str()` is useful for understanding large, odd-shaped named lists. But sometimes we wish to search the output, especially if it's large.

When writing to a file like so

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% str %>% as.character %>% writeLines("iris.txt")
```

The text file doesn't contain the expected content (although the file itself is created)

How can we write the exact content produced by `str()` in the console in a text file?

Comment: You can also use `ls.str(iris)` instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using `capture.output()`?

```
capture.output(str(iris), file = "iris.txt")
```